# why do the key arguments that regulate the size of a tk canvas fail to work after a button is added?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I was trying to build a window large enough that contains some widgets in it. So I passed some key arguments to regulate the size of the canvas and it worked as expected. However, when I added a button inside the canvas, the window returned to its original small size(which may be the default size).

I tested the value of width of height at the end of the code:
print(window["width"]) gives 700
print(window["height"]) gives 800

This further buffles me because if the width and height properties have the value of what I entered, why would the addition of the button prevent the window from demonstrating these properties?

```
import tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()

window=tk.Canvas(root,width=700,height=800) 
window.pack()

button=tk.Button(window,text="test button") #(1)
button.pack()#(2)
# the Canvas shows the wanted size when (1) and (2)is deleted

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I've spent hours on this bug,checking websites and videos but none helped. This is truely frustrating for a beginner like me. Please help me! I appreciate any explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Canvas` or `Frame` will shrink to the size it needs when a `widget` has been packed or grided. But you can pass `propagate` to explicitly tell it not to:

```
window=tk.Canvas(root,width=700,height=800)
window.pack()
window.propagate(0)
```

Alternatively you can use `place` method on your `Button` widget instead:

```
button.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.5)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It actually works! I found out that another way to fix this is to change the button's master from the window to the root, so that both the canvas and button are independent widgets in the root. Yeah place() is really a useful function. Thanks a lot!